# RethinkDB migrations and keeping actual schema

Tags: database-migration, rethinkdb, microservices

I just start to learn RethinkDB and I looking for best pracitcs on keep actual schema (e.g. tables what i need must be present).
I suppose to use rethink as message bridge between microservices. Api and Data parser
api: Creates document with state: 'pending' and subscribes to update
parser: Subscribed to changes, loads some data and update state to 'done'

In this case what right way to keep needed tables present? I don't want to auto create tables if not exists, cause I want to one microservice to maintain database.

I suppose, what api must raise some exception if table was not found. But I lazy to code some validation. And IMHO in this case exception must be raised on boot API service (to avoid errors at service work)

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It would answer many of these thoughts.